# Best way to Move/Merge Tables between 2 Azure SQL databases

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I have 2 Azure SQL databases, each with identical schemas.

Each database has about 200 tables.

I need to MOVE the data from 70 of the tables in db1 to db2

I need to MERGE the data from 5 of the tables in db1 to db2

One of the tables involved in the MOVE has 120 million rows and is 100GB in size.

Of all of the tools available to me what would you recommend I use to do this transfer?

Answer (score 0):

For merge operations SSIS may be your best option, and you can also consider it to move data.

For moving data you can also consider using elastic queries.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<password>';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL SQL_Credential  
WITH IDENTITY = '<username>',
SECRET = '<password>';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
WITH
(
    TYPE=RDBMS,
    LOCATION='<server>.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME='<db>',
    CREDENTIAL= SQL_Credential
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[source_table] (
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ...
)
WITH
(
    DATA_SOURCE = RemoteReferenceData
)

SELECT *
 INTO target_table
FROM source_table
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax, I am looking at this option for the 100GB table.

Comment: You are welcome! More information on below resource: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/